# Video playback is very slow over HDMI after Windows 10 upgrade

Tags: audio, drivers, video, windows-10, hdmi

I upgraded my Dell M3800 Precision 64 bit laptop to Windows 10 from Windows 8.1.

Prior to the upgrade I could plug an HDMI cable into it and attach it to my TV to watch Netflix, iPlayer, etc.

After the upgrade, those services play OK on the laptop, but as soon as I plug in the HDMI cable, the sound goes dead and the playback of the video starts to go really slow (a few frames a second).

I downloaded and installed the audio drivers for Windows 10 off the Dell website.

I tried to install the video drivers but it said I already had newer ones installed.

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: In sound Properties be sure hdmi is available on the playback tab and enabled

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is still a problem for you but I've had the same issue since upgrading to Windows 10.

I looked at the advanced properties for the HDMI playback device and the setting was defaulting to 16 bit DVD quality. On this setting the video on the external screen was choppy and there was no sound.

I changed the setting to 24 bit 48000HZ (studio quality) and the sound immediately started to play and there was no longer any lag to the video playback.

Comment: how do you get to those settings? I can't seem to find them.

Comment: This fixed my issue. @mateuscb You need to go to control panel --> Hardware and Sound --> Sound --> Right click on your HDMI output and go to properties --> Switch to advanced tab and there you can change it

Answer (score -2):

Scroll your mouse over the YouTube video and then click on the gear icon (round wheel with rough edges), in the popup window click where it says quality and lower it. I lowered mine to 360p and now it works fine.